# Using Stellaris/Tiva USB Library with uDMA?

Tags: c, usb, stellaris

Studying the TI docs about the Stellaris/Tiva USB library, I can't find if this library is usable with DMA transfer. In particular, Bulk Transfer device doesn't seem to offer config options for DMA. (The entire manual only mentions DMA for Host Audio, and mentions DMA for Mass Storage, but warning not to use it).

Does anyone know about this?

Note: I am referring to the USB Driver Library, not the Peripheral driver library. The latter does permit DMA use, but doesn't offer functions for device numeration.

Edit: As Ralf states (below), there is some documentation on the use of DMA with the Mass Storage Class, but this class is *intended* to be used with DMA - it seems to have many internal function which manage the DMA access, but strangely enough, the Bulk Transfer class does not have this facility (even though Mass Storage is using bulk transfer internally).

I don't think Mass Storage is a solution for me - the extra work of storing data as files doesn't seem compatible with the streaming nature of the ADC acquired samples.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples on the net that use `driverlib/udma.h` (https://github.com/yuvadm/tiva-c/blob/master/driverlib/udma.h), i.e. https://github.com/Emeryth/Stellaris-mass-storage-bootloader/blob/master/boot_usb_msc.c

On *page 313* of the TIVA doc are listed *inbuilt USB DMA functions*, their implementation is in **https://github.com/yuvadm/tiva-c/blob/master/usblib/usbdma.c** and  **https://github.com/yuvadm/tiva-c/blob/master/usblib/usblibpriv.h**

Comment: Hi Ralf, thanks for the links! I have been searching *a lot*, and somehow they didn't come up. One reason may be that they are for the GNU tool chain and/or for Tiva (I have the impression that Tiva's USB library is quite different). I do have the GNU tools installed but have been using CCS until now. A quick test showed compilation errors, but I'll have a more detailed look over the weekend. Cheers!